# Find Weeknumber in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

This must be simple, but I am not able to figure out.

I want to find the week number as an **Integer** in iphone.

This shows how to get a String
[Code](http://snipt.net/boydlee/get-week-number-of-any-given-month?key=18996834616dc1f6a45f3dabc8840df9)

```
-(NSString*) getWeekOfMonth {
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
 [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"W"];

 NSString *weekNumber = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];    
 [dateFormatter release];    
 return weekNumber;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `integerValue`:

```
NSInteger weekInt = [weekNumber integerValue];
```

Comment: ahh.. I just found it. How did i not think of this :( Should get a coffee soon. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int intWeekNumber = [weekNumber intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
CFAbsoluteTime currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CFTimeZoneRef currentTimeZone = CFTimeZoneCopyDefault();    
SInt32 weekNumber = CFAbsoluteTimeGetWeekOfYear(currentTime, currentTimeZone);
```